# ASP.NET Webform URL re writing not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have created an asp.net web form application, where I want to use different text in my URL instead of actual application page. For example
I have the URL as follows

> http://localhost:9802/Product.aspx

but I want the end users to see this URL as follows

> http://localhost:9802/Main/Accessories

Not I am already using URL Rewriting, but its not working.
Here is the code.

**Routeconfig.cs**

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
     }
```

Comment: can you share your code, so that we can exactly help what's not working ?

Comment: @mzh I have updated my question. I have EnableFriendlyUrls.

Answer (score 0):

Just EnableFriendlyUrls does't work when you talk about Url rewriting of ASP.NET.
Change your code as follows

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
        RegisterCustomRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }  

    public static void RegisterCustomRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute(
            "Main",
            "Accessories/",
            "~/Product.aspx"
        );
    }
```

> You can add different more pages in your custom function to apply url rewriting.

Comment: hello brother :P I am in GRID now.. watching you